# Exclude section numbers from links in ToC: non-numbered sections bug

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I use etoc [to exclude section numbers from links in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99268/8992). However, when I insert a non-numbered appexdix section — etoc adds a period:

[image]

I played with the code, and found that the problem is with `\etocthenumber` in `\etocsetstyle{section}` definition (without etoc the dot is not there). Is there a fix?

Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% heading styles:
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{teal}\large\sffamily}
  {\thetitle.\hspace{0.5cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{violet}\bfseries}
  {\hspace{0.75cm}\thetitle.\hspace{0.3cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\color{olive}\itshape}
  {\hspace{1.3cm}\thetitle.\hspace{0.3cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

% ToC styles:
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{2.55em} % space for a page number

\titlecontents{section}
    [3.8em] % 1.5em + 2.3em
    {\vspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\bfseries\large}
    {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
    {\normalsize\normalfont\rmfamily\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    [\vspace{0.1cm}]

\titlecontents{subsection}
    [5.2em] % 3.8em + 1.3em
    {\vspace{0.1cm}}
    {\contentslabel{1.4em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.4em}}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    []

\titlecontents{subsubsection}
    [6.5em] % 5.2em + 1.3em
    {\vspace{0.1cm}}
    {\contentslabel{1.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    []

\makeatletter
\let\perhapsprint\@firstofone
\patchcmd{\addtocontents}
  {\glossary\@gobble}
  {\glossary\@gobble\let\perhapsprint\@gobble}
  {}{}
\makeatother
%\newcommand{\perhapsprint}[1]{\ifprintprefix#1\fi}
%\newif\ifprintprefix
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{%
  \perhapsprint{\Roman{section}.}%
  \alph{subsection}%
}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{%
  \perhapsprint{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}.}%
  \arabic{subsubsection}%
}

% appendix:
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% exclude number from the link in ToC:
\usepackage{etoc}
\makeatletter
  % store the original table of contents macros (they are not modified by hyperref, only \contentsline is)
  \let\latchapter\l@chapter
  \let\latsection\l@section
  \let\latsubsection\l@subsection
  \let\latsubsubsection\l@subsubsection
  % then use the etoc package to feed the l@ macros with a filtered out data
  \etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}
  {\latchapter{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
  \etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
  {\latsection{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
  \etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
  {\latsubsection{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
  \etocsetstyle{subsubsection}{}{}
  {\latsubsubsection{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\roman{paragraph}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{H1}
\subsection{H2}
\subsubsection{H3}
\section{H1}
\subsection{H2}
\subsubsection{H3}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendices}
\begin{appendices}
  \subsection{H2}
  \subsubsection{H3}
  \subsection{H2}
  \subsubsection{H3}
  \subsection{H2}
  \subsubsection{H3}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

(I'm also [excluding section numbering in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219523/8992))

Comment: You are mixing `titletoc` with `etoc` and that's not right. Remove all the stuff related to `etoc` and the problem will disappear.

Comment: @karlkoeller: but I need `etoc` to exclude numbers from links to the sections. Is it possible to replace `titletoc` declarations with `etoc` ones?

Comment: Note that with your `titletoc` settings numbers are excluded from links, without the need of `etoc`

Comment: @karlkoeller: OMG! you right!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, in view of the other packages used by the OP's code, the simplest remedy is probably to drop use of [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc).

In case some users of `etoc` find this question, I nevertheless provide this answer to explain what could be the way with `etoc` to handle the problem: just use the `\etocifnumbered` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

% appendix:
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% exclude number from the link in ToC:
\usepackage{etoc}
\makeatletter
  % store the original table of contents macros (they are not modified by hyperref, only \contentsline is)
  \let\latchapter\l@chapter
  \let\latsection\l@section
  \let\latsubsection\l@subsection
  \let\latsubsubsection\l@subsubsection

  \etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}
  {\etocifnumbered
       {\latchapter{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
       {\latchapter{\etocname}{\etocpage}}}{}

  \etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
  {\etocifnumbered
       {\latsection{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
       {\latsection{\etocname}{\etocpage}}}{}

  \etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
  {\etocifnumbered
       {\latsubsection{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
       {\latsubsection{\etocname}{\etocpage}}}{}

  \etocsetstyle{subsubsection}{}{}
  {\etocifnumbered
       {\latsubsubsection{\numberline{\etocthenumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
       {\latsubsubsection{\etocname}{\etocpage}}}{}

\makeatother

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\roman{paragraph}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{H1}
\subsection{H2}
\subsubsection{H3}
\section{H1}
\subsection{H2}
\subsubsection{H3}

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendices}
\begin{appendices}
  \subsection{H2}
  \subsubsection{H3}
  \subsection{H2}
  \subsubsection{H3}
  \subsection{H2}
  \subsubsection{H3}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: table of contents with etoc]